# Overfitting a small data set through the ReLU activation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I would like to train a network by only using the `ReLU` activation and completely overfit the data. However, no matter how many different network structures I utilize (e.g., increasing the number of neurons and layers), I'm not able to reach a loss value close to zero.

It is important to emphasize that i) I don't want to use another activation function, and ii) for now, I won't be normalizing the data points.

```
n = 50
x = np.random.randint(50, 2000,  (n, 10))
y = np.random.randint(600, 4000,  (n, 1))

k = 16

model = tf.keras.Sequential([  
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(10,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(k, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(k, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(k, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(k, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) 
    ])

model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001))   
model.fit(x, y, epochs=1000, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

My current network is quite vanilla, and in my opinion, the `ReLU` activation should "easily" memorize/overfit the data especially when considering the size and dimension of the data set.  Is there a chance that I might be doing something wrong in my code? or What could be the reason that my network does not work?

Comment: Did you try changing your other hyperparameters?

Comment: @AloneTogether Hi, yes I did. I changed the learning rate, attached different callbacks. I don't know what else I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loss seems to go down to zero eventually if you add more neurons and increase the batch size and learning rate.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
np.random.seed(0)
tf.random.set_seed(0)

n = 50
x = np.random.randint(50, 2000,  (n, 10))
y = np.random.randint(600, 4000,  (n, 1))

k = 100

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(10,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(k, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(k, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(k, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(k, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
    ])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001))

history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=1000, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

loss = history.history['loss']

for epoch in [1, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000]:
    print('Epoch: {}, Loss: {:,.4f}'.format(epoch, loss[epoch - 1]))

# Epoch: 1, Loss: 7,371,788.0000
# Epoch: 10, Loss: 1,696,856.7500
# Epoch: 50, Loss: 523,101.4375
# Epoch: 100, Loss: 23,518.8301
# Epoch: 500, Loss: 88.4517
# Epoch: 1000, Loss: 0.0000
```

Comment: Then, I guess the problem was the number of neurons. Does that make sense to include more neurons than the number of dimensions? Cuz I'll have a larger data set in real.

Comment: It makes sense to include more neurons than the number of dimensions. 
Imagine your data points are 2-dimensional, a 2d point cannot move to the other side of a line without intersecting it. If you add a third dimension, then this becomes possible as you can move the point around the line. 
A model with 2 neurons per layer might not be able to cleanly separate the points by their class, because the class distribution is only separable in higher dimensions.
Try out this with a 2-neuron and 3-neuron-per-layer model, then you can see the effect: https://playground.tensorflow.org/

Comment: @Chillston Thanks for the great explanation!